# ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have the following TensorFlow code:

```
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(tf.cast(x, tf.float32), weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
```

But is throwing the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [?,5741,20000], [20000,128].
```

It says that `x` has the shape of (?,5741,20000). How could I transform the shape of `x` to (5741, 20000)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to work with tensors dot product instead of simple matrix multiplication in order to keep the batch size. This is answer is more general than [@mrry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574081/mrry)

```
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.tensordot(tf.cast(x, tf.float32), weights['h1'], [[2], [0]]), biases['b1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to matrix multiply 'x' with 'weights'. x has a shape of [5741, 20000] for one example, but when you feed examples in batches x will have a shape of [?, 5741, 20000]. Similarly, weights should also have a shape of [?, 20000, 128]. But, from the error, it looks like your weights are still [20000, 128] which tells me that you have some problem in your code which is not transforming the weights variable to shape [?, 20000, 128]. When you can figure this out, the error should go away. The result of matrix multiplication should have a shape of [?, 5741, 128]

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `x` the dynamic shape of `x` is `(1, 5741, 20000)`, you can transform its shape to `(5741, 20000)` using [`tf.squeeze()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) as follows:

```
x = tf.squeeze(x, axis=[0])
```