# ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](add, bias)' with input shapes:

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

**Done**

I am just trying to run and replicate the following project: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ . Basically until this point I have done everything as it is in the linked project but than I got the following issue:

**My Own Dataset - I have tried with the dataframe:**

- I have tried with his original dataset fully 100% his code but I still have the same error
- A.) having the 2 columns (1st column date and 2nd column target values),
- B.) time code in to the index and dataframe only containing  the target value.

**INPUT CODE:**

```
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

**OUTPUT ERROR:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1879   try:
-> 1880     c_op = pywrap_tf_session.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](add, bias)' with input shapes: [?,16], [16].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-146-278c5358bee6> in <module>
      1 # create and fit the LSTM network
      2 model = Sequential()
----> 3 model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
      4 model.add(Dense(1))
      5 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    520     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    521     try:
--> 522       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    523     finally:
    524       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    206           # and create the node connecting the current layer
    207           # to the input layer we just created.
--> 208           layer(x)
    209           set_inputs = True
    210 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    658 
    659     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 660       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    661 
    662     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    944     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
    945       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
--> 946                                                 input_list)
    947 
    948     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1082       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
   1083       outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
-> 1084           inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1085 
   1086       if outputs is None:

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    814       return tf.nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    815     else:
--> 816       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    817 
    818   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    854           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    855           inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
--> 856           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    857 
    858         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in call(self, inputs, mask, training, initial_state)
   1250         else:
   1251           (last_output, outputs, new_h, new_c,
-> 1252            runtime) = lstm_with_backend_selection(**normal_lstm_kwargs)
   1253 
   1254       states = [new_h, new_c]

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in lstm_with_backend_selection(inputs, init_h, init_c, kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias, mask, time_major, go_backwards, sequence_lengths, zero_output_for_mask)
   1645     # Call the normal LSTM impl and register the CuDNN impl function. The
   1646     # grappler will kick in during session execution to optimize the graph.
-> 1647     last_output, outputs, new_h, new_c, runtime = defun_standard_lstm(**params)
   1648     _function_register(defun_gpu_lstm, **params)
   1649 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3020     with self._lock:
   3021       (graph_function,
-> 3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in standard_lstm(inputs, init_h, init_c, kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias, mask, time_major, go_backwards, sequence_lengths, zero_output_for_mask)
   1386       input_length=(sequence_lengths
   1387                     if sequence_lengths is not None else timesteps),
-> 1388       zero_output_for_mask=zero_output_for_mask)
   1389   return (last_output, outputs, new_states[0], new_states[1],
   1390           _runtime(_RUNTIME_CPU))

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py in rnn(step_function, inputs, initial_states, go_backwards, mask, constants, unroll, input_length, time_major, zero_output_for_mask)
   4341     # the value is discarded.
   4342     output_time_zero, _ = step_function(
-> 4343         input_time_zero, tuple(initial_states) + tuple(constants))
   4344     output_ta = tuple(
   4345         tf.TensorArray(

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py in step(cell_inputs, cell_states)
   1364     z = backend.dot(cell_inputs, kernel)
   1365     z += backend.dot(h_tm1, recurrent_kernel)
-> 1366     z = backend.bias_add(z, bias)
   1367 
   1368     z0, z1, z2, z3 = tf.split(z, 4, axis=1)

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py in bias_add(x, bias, data_format)
   5961   if len(bias_shape) == 1:
   5962     if data_format == 'channels_first':
-> 5963       return tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias, data_format='NCHW')
   5964     return tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias, data_format='NHWC')
   5965   if ndim(x) in (3, 4, 5):

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    204     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    205     try:
--> 206       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    207     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    208       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in bias_add(value, bias, data_format, name)
   3376     else:
   3377       return gen_nn_ops.bias_add(
-> 3378           value, bias, data_format=data_format, name=name)
   3379 
   3380 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py in bias_add(value, bias, data_format, name)
    689   data_format = _execute.make_str(data_format, "data_format")
    690   _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
--> 691         "BiasAdd", value=value, bias=bias, data_format=data_format, name=name)
    692   _result = _outputs[:]
    693   if _execute.must_record_gradient():

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py in _apply_op_helper(op_type_name, name, **keywords)
    748       op = g._create_op_internal(op_type_name, inputs, dtypes=None,
    749                                  name=scope, input_types=input_types,
--> 750                                  attrs=attr_protos, op_def=op_def)
    751 
    752     # `outputs` is returned as a separate return value so that the output

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
    599     return super(FuncGraph, self)._create_op_internal(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    600         op_type, captured_inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def,
--> 601         compute_device)
    602 
    603   def capture(self, tensor, name=None, shape=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_op_internal(self, op_type, inputs, dtypes, input_types, name, attrs, op_def, compute_device)
   3563           input_types=input_types,
   3564           original_op=self._default_original_op,
-> 3565           op_def=op_def)
   3566       self._create_op_helper(ret, compute_device=compute_device)
   3567     return ret

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __init__(self, node_def, g, inputs, output_types, control_inputs, input_types, original_op, op_def)
   2040         op_def = self._graph._get_op_def(node_def.op)
   2041       self._c_op = _create_c_op(self._graph, node_def, inputs,
-> 2042                                 control_input_ops, op_def)
   2043       name = compat.as_str(node_def.name)
   2044 

~/anaconda3/envs/tfall/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def)
   1881   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
   1882     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
-> 1883     raise ValueError(str(e))
   1884 
   1885   return c_op

ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](add, bias)' with input shapes: [?,16], [16].
```

**Tried Solutions**

- no actual solution in the answers - https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/ipbse4/valueerror_shape_must_be_at_least_rank_3_but_is/
- no actual solution in the answers - https://github.com/tensorflow/recommenders/issues/237
- no actual solution in the answers, different input code - [ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162787/valueerror-shape-must-be-rank-2-but-is-rank-3-for-matmul)

Comment: I didn't understand what is your problem. This error is because of your input shape is incompatible with the expected input shape. What is the data have you used? Is it the same that exist in the first link you have provided? If it is something else would you please share the shape and structure of the data?

Comment: I have tried with the dataframe: A.) having the 2 columns (1st column date and 2nd column target values), B.) time code in to the index and dataframe only containing the target value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- I switched to AWS EC2 SageMaker "Python [conda env:tensorflow2_p36] " so this is the exact pre made environment "tensorflow2_p36"
- As I have read it in some other places it is probably library collision maybe with NumPy.

Answer (score 9):

I continue to see this problem in 2022 when using LSTMs or GRUs in Sagemaker with conda_tensorflow2_p38 kernel. Here's my workaround:

Early in your notebook, before defining your model, set

```
tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format("channels_last")
```

I know it looks weird to set image data format when you aren't processing pics, but this somehow works around the dimension error.

To demonstrate that this isn't just a library mismatch in the default kernel, here's something I sometimes add to the beginning of my notebooks to update to the latest library versions (currently TF 2.9.0). It did not solve the error above.

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --upgrade pip tensorflow numpy scikit-learn pandas
```

Comment: It works like a magic! Thank you @David Abrahams

Comment: I just spent almost an entire day trying to fix this issue and this solved it for me. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered same issue while using aws sagemaker. Changing `lstm` to `tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` worked for me.

in your case:

```
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

to

```
model.add(tf.compat.v1.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

```
import keras
keras.backend.set_image_data_format("channels_last")
```

Comment: Please don't repeat answers