# Tensoflow: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node bidirectional/forward_lstm/lstm_cell_1/BiasAdd}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to build a model using multi-modal 3D images with the shape `(2,128,128,64)` (`channels_first`) in tensorflow keras. The code is as follows:

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPool3D, GlobalAveragePooling3D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D,RepeatVector,Bidirectional,LSTM,TimeDistributed,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import CategoricalCrossentropy

tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')   

inputs = keras.Input((2, 128, 128, 64))

x = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation='relu' , name='conv1')(inputs) #32
x = Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu",name='conv2')(x) #64
x = MaxPool3D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling3D()(x)
x = Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

dense2 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x) 

x = RepeatVector(2)(x)
LSTM1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(64,activation='relu',return_sequences=True,dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))(x)
LSTM1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(32, activation='relu',return_sequences=True,dropout=0.2,recurrent_dropout=0.2))(LSTM1)
dense4 = TimeDistributed(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))(LSTM1)
dense1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))(dense4) 
model = Model(inputs, outputs=[dense1,dense2])
```

I am getting the following value error in the LSTM layer.

```py
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lstm_cell_1" (type LSTMCell).

Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node bidirectional/forward_lstm/lstm_cell_1/BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](bidirectional/forward_lstm/lstm_cell_1/MatMul, bidirectional/forward_lstm/lstm_cell_1/split_1)' with input shapes: [?,64], [64].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32)
  • states=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64), dtype=float32)')
  • training=False
```

I saw this post [ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](add, bias)' with input shapes:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036975/valueerror-shape-must-be-at-least-rank-3-but-is-rank-2-for-node-biasadd) which recommends using a 'channels_last' format, but is there a way to train the model keeping the 'channels_first' format?

Comment: I think it is not about channel axis, if possible please share reproducible code.

Comment: HI @Innat, I edited the code. Could you please check if you get the same error?